# Parsing json response into dict using yaml

Tags: python, json, yaml

I am trying to parse a string into a dictionary using python's yaml module. I am getting exception when the value has ":" in it. Here is my sample code

```
import yaml

input = '''{"method":"Send", "buf":{"html":"<html><body><div style=\"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:times new roman, new york, times, serif;font-size:12pt\"><ul><li>Sample message</li><li>Parse it<br></li></ul></div></body></html>","text":"\t* Sample message\n\t* Parse it\n"}} '''
yaml.load(input)
```

I get the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webmailparser.py", line 9, in ?
    yaml.load(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 58, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 42, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 35, in get_single_node
    if not self.check_event(StreamEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 93, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 138, in parse_implicit_document_start
    StreamEndToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 252, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_plain()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 679, in fetch_plain
    self.tokens.append(self.scan_plain())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 1308, in scan_plain
    "Please check http://pyyaml.org/wiki/YAMLColonInFlowContext for details.")
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a plain scalar
  in "<string>", line 1, column 58:
     ... "html":"<html><body><div style="color:#000; background-color:#ff ... 
                                         ^
found unexpected ':'
  in "<string>", line 1, column 63:
     ... ":"<html><body><div style="color:#000; background-color:#fff; fo ... 
                                         ^
Please check http://pyyaml.org/wiki/YAMLColonInFlowContext for details.
```

Is there any workaround for this?

This worked

```
import yaml

input = r'{"method":"Send", "buf":{"html":"<html><body><div style=\"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:times new roman, new york, times, serif;font-size:12pt\"><ul><li>Sample message</li><li>Parse it<br></li></ul></div></body></html>","text":"\t* Sample message\n\t* Parse it\n"}} '
print yaml.load(input)
```

Comment: This looks like a correct error to me.  The "html" key isn't properly escaped, so the value of HTML key ends at ``style=`` making stuff after it an error.  The value you're parsing isn't valid JSON.

Comment: yep..Thanks..I thought \" properly escaped it. But it works when have the entire input prefixed with 'r'

Comment: Why not just use the `json` module?

Comment: yep..I tried with simplejson(without prefix r) and got the same error. Now with prefix r it works fine